# Ruby on rails migration error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I installed a gem `acts-as-taggable-on` whenever i tried to run `rails db:migrate` it would output this:

```
C:\Sites\novosti>rails db:migrate
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

Directly inheriting from ActiveRecord::Migration is not supported. Please specify the Rails release the migration was written for:

  class ActsAsTaggableOnMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration[4.2]
C:/Sites/novosti/db/migrate/20170708123900_acts_as_taggable_on_migration.acts_as_taggable_on_engine.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
StandardError: Directly inheriting from ActiveRecord::Migration is not supported. Please specify the Rails release the migration was written for:

  class ActsAsTaggableOnMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration[4.2]
C:/Sites/novosti/db/migrate/20170708123900_acts_as_taggable_on_migration.acts_as_taggable_on_engine.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

So i just added `[5.1]` and it fixed the problem but another one appeared

```
C:\Sites\novosti>rails db:migrate
== 20170708123900 ActsAsTaggableOnMigration: migrating ========================
-- create_table(:tags)
   -> 0.0028s
-- create_table(:taggings)
   -> 0.0033s
-- add_index(:taggings, :tag_id)
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

Index name 'index_taggings_on_tag_id' on table 'taggings' already exists
C:/Sites/novosti/db/migrate/20170708123900_acts_as_taggable_on_migration.acts_as_taggable_on_engine.rb:23:in `up'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
ArgumentError: Index name 'index_taggings_on_tag_id' on table 'taggings' already exists
C:/Sites/novosti/db/migrate/20170708123900_acts_as_taggable_on_migration.acts_as_taggable_on_engine.rb:23:in `up'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: It seems that the index `'index_taggings_on_tag_id'` has already been created (maybe from a previous failed migration), try deleting it from the DB and run your migration again.

Answer (score 1):

Index name on a table should be unique. So this is an error from db as the the index already exists. Please drop the index on the table of the db before migration or you can remove the add_index in migration if the index is already ok in the table

Comment: I tried removing `add_index` but that caused me to add more `[5.0]` and when i did that another error popped up

No indexes found on taggings with the options provided.
C:/Sites/novosti/db/migrate/20170709090702_add_missing_unique_indices.acts_as_taggable_on_engine.rb:7:in `up'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
ArgumentError: No indexes found on taggings with the options provided.
C:/Sites/novosti/db/migrate/20170709090702_add_missing_unique_indices.acts_as_taggable_on_engine.rb:7:in `up'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'

Comment: Could you explain me more about how you use it? I hope that you are trying to check the pre-existence of the index before the operation, Can you share/check the line?

Comment: I wish i could use it but its no help i can't use it at all i need to run db:migrate but i can't because of the error it causes me i dropped the whole database any when i installed it it said that the index ting already exists